# How can I create a SharePoint List from an existing one using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-template, ms-flow

I want to create a flow that automate the creation of lists using a REST API, well i figure out how to do it from the existing templates (like Custom list, Issue Tracking ... etc) using their **BaseTemplate** number, now i want to create the list from an existing List i already created and customised in my site.

[image]

As you know, we can create a list from an existing list in the interface, check below the picture:

[image]

Now i bet there is a way to automate this using the REST API, I just don't how or what kind of Information should I get in order to automate this.

Thanks.

Comment: Save the list as a template. and use that template while creating the list in your same flow action.

Comment: Okay, i understand your answer, how can i specify in my action the id or something that identify my template list, in other words i can't find specification for this template like the existing ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible. What you can do is - create a content type with all your required columns. create a list in your actions and then add the content type to the list and make it default content type. [Add content type using rest](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37594.sharepoint-online-add-content-type-to-list-using-rest-api.aspx).

Or you can write managed code using Azure functions and call that in your flow.
[Change content type ordering using c#](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37594.sharepoint-online-add-content-type-to-list-using-rest-api.aspx)

Comment: this is the only method i could find, indeed it works. now i just need to change the content type default (change it from "item" to the new assigned content type)